# Laravel 5.3 on shared hosting; Page::findBySlug() returns null

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, composer-php, slug

I just pushed a Laravel website onto a shared hosting. Copied the public folder to the /www, changed the index.php to reflect the path change and configured my .htaccess, etc.

At first I was simply getting an error, telling me that Page::findBySlug() returned null. Checked again with dd(), was and still is null.

FrontendController@index is looking like this

```
public function index($slug)
{
    $page = Page::findBySlug($slug);
    $pageTemplate = $page->templates->first();
    return view('frontend.pages.index', compact('page','pageTemplate'));
}
```

and after toying with dd() for a while, it now sends me to the custom 500 unless it's supposed to pull the slug from db, in which case I get a custom 404.

EDIT: I pulled the same version of the app but with it being already installed (instead of rolling with composer instal) from the testing platform and it simply works so I doubt it has anything to do with the hosting. I'd still appreciate an answer given that I'd like to do it the correct way. Is there anything I should setup slugs-wise after running a fresh install?

What am I missing here? Thanks.

Comment: do you have a page with that slug in your database?

Comment: How can you run composer install on shared hosting? Just copy everything you've got to server using ftp or sftp.

Comment: There are limitations on shared hosting regarding terminal access and installing things like composer, node etc to a varying degree depending on the provider. So the best is to copy/ftp upload your project from local/development machine to server. Refer http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/laravel/2410/deployment/7970/laravel-5-app-on-shared-hosting-on-linux-server#t=201612080510332936254 for instructions on uploading Laravel project to a shared hosting. Hope it helps.

Comment: The db only has a few slugs for pages such as privacy/contact and such.

Composer install ran just fine on the hosting. I did copy it once but boy did it took ages.

Everything hosting/project wise seems to be fine now.

I got thrown into this 4 month-in-dev project as a junior-dev, day 1. I'm the only dev here and had to change/fix bunch of stuff but boy, it seems to be fine now. Thanks, peeps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed by php artisan route:clear.
Apparently route:cache wasn't the way to go.

Answer (score 1):

Try `$page= Page::where('slug',$slug)->first();`

Comment: It's having none of it. Still null.

Answer (score 0):

Try to update your php veersion to 7.0 .

Comment: This is not an answer, please comment next time.